# for..in loop loops over non-numeric indexes “clean” and “remove”

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

This is something very basic I might be missing here but I haven't seen such result till now.

I have a for loop where options.headers.length is `3`. And in for loop I am dynamically creating a table header. Ideally this loop should run three times for `0 1 and 2` but when I have printed index it's printing `0,1,2,clean and remove`. I haven't seen `clean and remove` as indexes. I know this information is not sufficient enough but if you have any clue please suggest. something might be overriding this is all I am concluded too after my debugging.

```
for (index in options.headers)
```

Comment: For arrays you should use a simple `for` loop, not a `for in` loop: something like `for (var index = 0, len = options.headers.length; index < len; i++)`

Comment: clean and remove are properties.. when you use (for in), it assumes option.header as an object and it will get ALL keys related to its object. You must use @Andy solution instead.

Comment: From MDN: [[for..in] traverses all enumerable properties of an object and its prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Does no-one cache the length of their arrays anymore :/

Comment: How for in loop works for one page and don't work in another page..
In one page It iterated 3 times and another it Iterated 5 times. It should be consistent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't want to iterate `clean` and `remove` then change the loop to:

```
for (var i=0; i< options.headers.length;i++){
//use i for getting the array data
}
```

if you use `for (index in options.headers)` it will iterate for `non-numeric` keys also.

Answer (score 2):

1. don use just index (as that is = window.index = global = bad) use var index
   (read more here https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=globals+javascript+bad)
2. you have to check does the array has it as own property or maybe its some function (more after answer)

---

```
for (var index in options.headers) {
    if (options.headers.hasOwnProperty(index) {
         // code here
    }
}
```

more about #2:

let's say we have

```
var array = [0,1,2,3];
```

and besides that, extending array with function (arrays can have functions in javascript and strings too)

```
Array.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    alert('Hello');
};
```

then your loop would print sayHello as part of the array, but that's not it's own property, only the arrays

Answer (score 1):

I assume that options.headers is an Array?

This happens when you (or some framework you load) adds methods to the Array prototype. The "for in" loop will enumerate also these added methods. Hence you should do the loop for an array with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < options.headers.length; i++)
```

That way you will only get the real values instead of added methods.